# Proving $\int_0^a x^b dx=\frac{a^{b+1}}{b+1}$

Tags: riemann-integration, step-function

I want to show that $\int_0^a x^b dx=\frac{a^{b+1}}{b+1}$. Whereby $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. I know this isn't too hard to prove with the power rule etc however I would like to form a proof using step functions. Here is my attempt but I can't quite get there!

First defining step functions $\phi, \psi$:

$$\phi=\sum^n_{j=1}\left(\frac{a(j-1)}{n}\right)^b\chi_{(a(j-1)/n,a(j)/n)}$$

$$\psi=\sum^n_{j=1}\left(\frac{aj}{n}\right)^b\chi_{(a(j-1)/n,a(j)/n)}$$

Hence:

$$\int \phi=\sum^n_{j=1}\left(\frac{a(j-1)}{n}\right)^b\left(\frac{a(j)}{n}-\frac{(a(j-1)}{n}\right)$$

$$\int \phi=\frac{a^{b+1}}{n}\sum^n_{j=1}\left(\frac{j-1}{n}\right)^b$$

$$\int \phi=\frac{a^{b+1}}{n^{b+1}}\sum^n_{j=1}(j-1)^b=\frac{a^{b+1}}{n^{b+1}}\sum^{n-1}_{j=1}(j)^b$$

So

$$\int \psi=\frac{a^{b+1}}{n^{b+1}}\sum^n_{j=1}(j)^b$$

Hence as $n\rightarrow \infty$:

$$\int \psi-\int \phi =\frac{a^{b+1}}{n^{b+1}}\left(\sum^n_{j=1}(j)^b-\sum^{n-1}_{j=1}(j)^b\right)=\frac{a^{b+1}}{n^{b+1}}j^n\rightarrow 0$$

So I know it is Riemann integrable, however I am now struggling to get the final form I want $\frac{a^{b+1}}{b+1}$. Could anyone give me a hand finishing this off? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your step functions seem to have a slight error: The $a$ should be included into the power as $x = a\cdot \frac{j-1}{n}$ and not just $x=\frac{j-1}{n}$. With your choice the potential values of $x$ inside the sum of $\phi$ only runs from $0$ to $1$ and not from $0$ to $a$. Recomputing should give the desired output.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: Happy that I could help you!

Comment: Sorry one more thing! How can we go from $\frac{a^{b+1}}{n^{b+1}}\sum^n_{j=1}(j)^b$ to $\frac{a^{b+1}}{b+1}$?

Comment: If you include the $n$ into the power $j^b$ you get a converging geometric series with $q=\frac{j}{n}\leq 1$ which converges to $\frac{1}{1-q}$. That should do the trick

Comment: So, $\frac{a^{b+1}}{n}\sum^n_{j=1}(\frac{j}{n})^b=\frac{a^{b+1}}{n}\frac{1}{1-j/n}$. Then $\frac{a^{b+1}}{n}\frac{1}{1-j/n}=\frac{a^{b+1}}{n-j}$? Still can't get it! Sorry!

Comment: Sorry, I was totally wrong. This is not geometric series, this is a summation using the same exponent (and no increasing one).

Comment: So how could we finish the identity then? Could you perhaps add to your answer?

Comment: There exist only very complex formulas (Faulhaber's formula) for calculating the general sum $\sum_{j=1}^n j^b$ for $b\in\mathbb{N}$. However we are only interested in the limit for $n\to\infty$, so we only need the factor in front of the $n^{b+1}$-term. As seen here https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhabersche_Formel we get $\sum_{j=1}^n j^b = \frac{n^{b+1}}{b+1} + \frac{n^b}{2} + \mathcal{O}(n^{b-1})\to \frac{n^{b+1}}{b+1}$ and multiplying with $\frac{1}{n^{b+1}}$ gives us the factor $\frac{1}{b+1}$